# Make the default location for all save and open actions Google Drive File Stream

Tags: macos, file, google, google-apps

Using macOS Mojave or High Sierra, is there a way to change the default file location for all save and open actions to Google Drive File Stream?

On Windows I would change it in the registry to `g:\users\%username%`. What is the equivalent on macOS? We are working with HIPAA data and I need to redirect all file activity away from the local computer onto the encrypted, shared platform.

Answer (score 1):

By default, there is no way to do this in Mac OS.

However, you can do it with [Default Folder X](https://stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/index.html), an app which is specifically designed to set default open and save folders. (Hence the name.)

It is a great app from a long, long, long-time Mac developer. Highly recommended. Comes with a free 30-day trial.